# Clean up user profile database - Remove user marked with bDeleted=1

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

I have SharePoint 2016 set up with ADI. MySite and everything configured and working properly.

Users were imported without any filters and I got almost 20K users. I have applied filter to get rid of disabled users but not able to bring the users numbers down to active users which will be 10k.

When I execute :

```
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -GetNonImportedObjects $true
```

I can see almost 4k users but when I execute :

```
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```

It completes successfully but none of users were purged from the first command. I also ran clean up mysite job couple times to check if this will do any better. 
Another test, I ran the SQL query mentioned below and got almost 10K rows back which seems like kind of close to accurate. Any help?

```
select * from [upa].[UserProfile_Full] nolock 
where bDeleted=1
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the MySite Cleanup job is running and has recently run?

Comment: Yes. its running once a day. but I ran it several times earlier , basically after each PS execution . I can also check at history page it shows mysite clean up job succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out this is a know issue and a fix will be out in August CU for 2016 which came out today and this issue is mentioned in the description. Commands I mentioned above will not clean up user profile in 2016.

Functionality has changed in 2016 : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2017/05/22/sharepoint-2016-mysitecleanup-job-functionality-changes/

For the CU : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011049/august-8-2017-update-for-sharepoint-server-2016-kb4011049

HTH